# Matching values conditioned on overlapping Intervals and ID

Tags: r, dataframe, lubridate

I am having difficulties at manipulating the following data structures:

Attributes Data Frame:

```
ID  Begin_A      End_A        Interval                         Value
5   2017-03-01   2017-03-10   2017-03-01 UTC--2017-03-10 UTC   Cat1
10  2017-12-01   2017-12-02   2017-12-01 UTC--2017-12-02 UTC   Cat2
5   2017-03-01   2017-03-03   2017-03-01 UTC--2017-03-03 UTC   Cat3
10  2017-12-05   2017-12-10   2017-12-05 UTC--2017-12-10 UTC   Cat4
```

Bookings Data Frame:

```
ID  Begin_A      End_A        Interval 
5   2017-03-03   2017-03-05   2017-03-03 UTC--2017-03-05 UTC
6   2017-05-03   2017-05-05   2017-05-03 UTC--2017-05-05 UTC
8   2017-03-03   2017-03-05   2017-03-03 UTC--2017-03-05 UTC
10  2017-12-05   2017-12-06   2017-12-05 UTC--2017-12-06 UTC
```

Desired outcome frame (Bookings):

```
ID  Begin_A      End_A        Interval                        Attribute_value
5   2017-03-03   2017-03-05   2017-03-03 UTC--2017-03-05 UTC  Cat1,Cat3
6   2017-05-03   2017-05-05   2017-05-03 UTC--2017-05-05 UTC  NA
8   2017-03-03   2017-03-05   2017-03-03 UTC--2017-03-05 UTC  NA
10  2017-12-05   2017-12-06   2017-12-05 UTC--2017-12-06 UTC  Cat4
```

Code for the data frames:

```
library(lubridate)
# Attributes data frame:
date1 <- as.Date(c('2017-3-1','2017-12-1','2017-3-1','2017-12-5'))
date2 <- as.Date(c('2017-3-10','2017-12-2','2017-3-3','2017-12-10'))
attributes <- data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow=4, ncol = 5)) 
names(attributes) <- c("ID","Begin_A", "End_A", "Interval", "Value")
attributes$ID <- as.numeric(c(5,10,5,10))
attributes$Begin_A <-date1
attributes$End_A <-date2
attributes$Interval <-attributes$Begin_A %--% attributes$End_A
attributes$Value<- as.character(c("Cat1","Cat2","Cat3","Cat4"))

### Bookings data frame:

date1 <- as.Date(c('2017-3-3','2017-5-3','2017-3-3','2017-12-5'))
date2 <- as.Date(c('2017-3-5','2017-5-5','2017-3-5','2017-12-6'))
bookings <- data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow=4, ncol = 4)) 
names(bookings) <- c("ID","Begin_A", "End_A", "Interval")
bookings$ID <- as.numeric(c(5,6,8,10))
bookings$Begin_A <-date1
bookings$End_A <-date2
bookings$Interval <-bookings$Begin_A %--% bookings$End_A
```

The procedure to arrive at my outcome frame should be the following: 
Take the ID from bookings, filter all rows of the attributes data frame where attributes ID matches the booking ID. Check which of the rows with matching attribute ID also have overlapping time intervals (int_overlaps from lubridate). Then take the respective value from the Value column and print each of them in the Attribute_value column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution from `tidyverse`.

```
library(tidyverse)

attributes2 <- attributes %>%
  select(-Interval) %>%
  gather(Type, Date, ends_with("_A")) %>%
  select(-Type) %>%
  group_by(Value) %>%
  complete(Date = full_seq(Date, period = 1), ID) %>%
  ungroup()

bookings2 <- bookings %>%
  select(-Interval) %>%
  gather(Type, Date, ends_with("_A")) %>%
  select(-Type) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  complete(Date = full_seq(Date, period = 1)) %>%
  ungroup()

bookings3 <- bookings2 %>%
  left_join(attributes2, by = c("ID", "Date")) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(Attribute_value = toString(sort(unique(Value)))) %>%
  mutate(Attribute_value = ifelse(Attribute_value %in% "", NA, Attribute_value))

bookings4 <- bookings %>% left_join(bookings3, by = "ID")
bookings4
  ID    Begin_A      End_A                       Interval Attribute_value
1  5 2017-03-03 2017-03-05 2017-03-03 UTC--2017-03-05 UTC      Cat1, Cat3
2  6 2017-05-03 2017-05-05 2017-05-03 UTC--2017-05-05 UTC            <NA>
3  8 2017-03-03 2017-03-05 2017-03-03 UTC--2017-03-05 UTC            <NA>
4 10 2017-12-05 2017-12-06 2017-12-05 UTC--2017-12-06 UTC            Cat4
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. In my actual data I have long time frames in the attributes data frame, which leads to very big data frames which R seems to be struggling with. I split up my data frame  but the data frames are still gigantic. How do I modify the "complete(Date = full_seq(Date, period = 1), ID) %>%" so that the jumps are in months and not in days? this could help making my data frames a bit smaller.

Comment: @JoshuaZecha Good question. I don't have an answer right now because the example you provided have intervals restricted to the same month and it is difficult to experiment what approach can achieve the one month jump. You may want to ask a new question with examples through several months.

Comment: I followed your advice and posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46839455/matching-values-between-data-frames-based-on-overlapping-dates