# Make data table using matched values from two data tables using R

Tags: r, data.table

I have two `data.tables`(a and b) using R which are approx 10,000 rows each. Each `data.table`contains three columns, x, y, and z. The z values are unique in each `data.table`. Each `data.table` shares a number of identical x and y values. What I need to do, is create a new `data.table` (c) which contains only the rows from a, where the x and y values are identical to those in b.

Here is an example of what I need to achieve.

data table a

```
x    y      z
a    1    100
a    6    120
c    5    234
b    3    567
d    8    645
f    7    487
```

data table b

```
x    y     z
a    1    904
b    6    120
c    7    765
e    3    567
d    8    329
a    0    638
```

And data table c (the newly created data table) should look like this

```
x    y     z
a    1    100
d    8    645
```

I've looked here ([Matching values between data frames based on overlapping dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46839455/matching-values-between-data-frames-based-on-overlapping-dates)), but it didn't quite get me to where I needed to be.

Here's the code to generate the example `data.tables`.

```
library(data.table)

x<-c("a","a","c","b","d","f")
y<-c(1,6,5,3,8,7)
z<-c(100,120,234,567,645,487)
a<-data.frame(x,y,z)
rm(x,y,z)

x<-c("a","b","c","e","d","a")
y<-c(1,6,7,3,8,0)
z<-c(904,120,765,567,329,638)
b<-data.frame(x,y,z)

setDT(a)
setDT(b)
```

Happy to take a suggestion that uses traditional `data.frames`

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple `merge` will do it:

```
merge(a, b, by=c("x","y"))
```

By default, `merge` keeps only rows from both datasets where there is a match; you can change this behavior with the `all`, `all.x`, and `all.y` args, but here you don't need to.

If you don't want the `z` values from datatable `b`, do this:

```
merge(a, b[,.(x,y)], by=c("x","y"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
# Note that they should be different values of z for identical x and y
# The following options assume that you also want to keep this information i.e. z values 
# from a and b for matched columns x and y
dplyr::inner_join(a, b, by = c("x", "y")) # option 1
merge(a, b, by = c("x","y")) # option 2
# option 3 using DT
setkeyv(a, c("x","y"))
setkeyv(b, c("x","y"))
a[b, nomatch = 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, a `dplyr` approach:

```
library(dplyr)
c <- a %>% semi_join(b, by = c("x", "y"))

> c
  x y   z
1 a 1 100
2 d 8 645
```